# How can I concatenate non-reactive values with reactive value for a graph title? R Shiny

Tags: r, plot, shiny, levelplot

I am having trouble naming a graph title that contains a normal string AND reactive value/s.

I'm trying to do something like this: 
main = "Examination of: " + input$userInput

The error message is: non-numeric argument to binary operator. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code could give you what you needed.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  uiOutput("test"),
  plotOutput("plot1")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dummy", "Select one value", c(mtcars$qsec))
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, main = paste0("this is main ",input$dummy,""))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The usage of `selectInput` is for testing your requirement. Make the needful changes for your actual problem.

Comment: If the user decided to select multiple inputs, say: X, Y, and Z. How do you display the title as "this is main X, Y, Z". The code above gave the title: "this is main X, this is main Y, this is main Z"

Comment: Then your `main` parameter in `plot` function should be like this `main = paste0("this is main ",input$X,", ",input$Y,", ", input$Z," ")`